# How do you pass an onClick function to grandchild component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm just starting out with React, adapting the tic tac toe tutorial for my case.
I'm trying to click on the grandchild component  to change the state of the grandparent component . Code is as follows:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fields: [
        {
          id: 1,
          show: false
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          show: false
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  handleClick(i) {
    const fields = this.state.fields.slice();
    fields[i].show = true;
    this.setState({fields: fields});
  }
  
  render() {return <Preview />}
      
}

const Preview = (props) => {
  
  return (
    <div className="preview">
      {props.fields.map((field) => (
        <Field data={field} key={field.id} onClick={ props.onClick(field.id) }/>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const Field = props => {
  
  return (
    <div className="field" onClick={ props.onClick } />
  );
};
```

I get a TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined from this line:

```
handleClick(i) {
const fields = this.state.fields.slice();
```

Comment: but you're not passing any props to `<Preview />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issues

1. `this` of the `App` class isn't bound to the `handleClick` function. This is cause of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined` error.
2. You are mutating your state object. Slicing the array creates a new array reference, but `fields[i].show = true;` mutates the object reference in state.
3. You don't pass `fields` or `onClick` props to `Preview`.
4. The `onClick` callback isn't called correctly in `Preview`.

## Solution

1. Bind `this` to the handler or convert to arrow function so it is automatically bound.

   ```
   constructor(props){
     ...
     this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
   }
   ```

   or

   ```
   handleClick = (i) => { ..... };
   ```
2. DON'T MUTATE STATE. Shallow copy state *then* update properties.

   ```
   handleClick = (id) => {
     this.setState(prevState => ({
       fields: prevState.fields.map((field) => {
         return field.id === id ? {
           ...field,
           show: true,
         } : field;
       }),
     }));
   };
   ```
3. Pass `fields` and `handleClick` as `onClick` to `Preview`.

   ```
   render() {
     return (
       <Preview
         fields={this.state.fields}
         onClick={this.handleClick}
       />
     );
   }
   ```
4. Call `props.onClick` correctly with the id.

   ```
   {props.fields.map((field) => (
     <Field
       data={field}
       key={field.id}
       onClick={() => props.onClick(field.id)}
     />
   ))}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I've added some explanations, check the comments

```
  // [...]

  render() {
    // Here you need to pass "fields" and "handleClick" as props:
    return <Preview fields={this.state.fields} onClickField={this.handleClick} />
  }
      
}

const Preview = (props) => {
  // Here you get the props:
  const { fields, onClickField } = props;

  // Your onclick was a function call instead of just a function
  return (
    <div className="preview">
      {fields.map((field) => (
        <Field 
          data={field}
          key={field.id}
          onClick={() => onClickField(field.id) }
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const Field = props => {
  
  return (
    <div className="field" onClick={ props.onClick } />
  );
};
```